# NIFI || Send Mail only for True boolean expression

Tags: apache-nifi

I am calculating value using below expression:
${alert:gt(${Lower}):or(${alert:lt(${UPPER})})} which in turn is returning either True or false value.

As per requirement I have to send a mail notification for True condition only.
can someone tell me suitable condition to send only true condition from above calculation.

[image]

Comment: before `PutEmail` add the `RouteOnAttribute` processor where you could check the required value / expression and forward to notification only valid flow files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before `PutEmail` add the `RouteOnAttribute` processor where you could check the required value / expression and forward to notification only valid flow files